# Expo Barcode Scanner show output with line break

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code

i have created a barcode/QR scanner react native app using expo, and everything works fine, i can scan Qrcodes and get results, However the issue arises when i want to display the output. The data object returned is displayed as a single line although it has a couple of properties within it. I want to add line breaks to it at the end of any property(ends with semi colon) so i decided to use regex to replace the semi colon at the end of any property with a new line flag however that doesn't work.`{data.replace(/;/g, "\n")}` How can i achieve this

```
 useEffect(() => {
const getBarCodeScannerPermissions = async () => {
  const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
  setHasPermission(status === "granted");
};
getBarCodeScannerPermissions();
}, []);

const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {  //data parsed from the Qr code
setObjectValue (data,type)
setScanned(true);
setData(data)
setMainModal(true)
 };

return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <BarCodeScanner
    onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
    style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, styles.minicontainer]}
  />
   <MainModal>   //modal popup containing the scanned QRinformation to be shown
  <Text style={{ whiteSpace: "pre-line" }}>
  {data.replace(/;/g, "\n")}
  </Text>
 </MainModal>
</View>
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm it seems like that should work. I guess you could try splitting and then mapping?

```js
{data.split(";").filter(t=>t && t.trim().length>0).map(text=>(
  <Text style={{whiteSpace:'pre-line'}}>
    {text}{'\n'}
  </Text>
}
```

Comment: not sure why it not working, I.e. Am scanning a Qr code containing wifi info and the ouptut is as flows `WIFI:T:WPA;S:Highspeed;P:fifa2022;` i believe S is the wifi name and P is the password however the replace is ignored

Comment: it has worked, thanks for the help